# rails query order results by arbitrary order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an Order model which has the following attributes:

```
submitted_date :date
completed_date :date
accepted_date  :date
```

Im using these fields to determine the order's status with the following code block:

```
def status
    if completed_date.present?
      "Fulfilled"
    elsif accepted_date.present? && submitted_date.present? && completed_date.blank?
      "Accepted"
    elsif submitted_date.present? && accepted_date.blank? && completed_date.blank?
      "Submitted"
    else
      "Open"
    end
  end
```

I totally spaced it when building the application and I didnt realize that the user would want to see the results ordered in the following order:

Open,
Submitted,
Accepted,
Fulfilled

I probably should have used an integer field to use as an enum to determine the status of an order, but I've built up a lot of functionality around the above structure.

What Im wondering is if it's possible to order the query so that the results are ordered by the above arbitrary order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ordering by the most complete status would do the trick. Open order will have a nil date so should be order properly

Order.order(submitted_date: :desc, completed_date: :desc, accepted_date: :desc)

playing with the `:desc/:asc` option and `.reverse` should do the trick.

For another iteration, one approach would be to have a state machine, having a status enum column, a date for each step. validating the required condition would progress the order to the next step